# How can I configure Rhapsody editor to en a line with 0x0A instead of 0x0D 0x0A?

Tags: editor, line, termination, rhapsody

The Rhapsody source code editor is terminating lines with the Windows type line termination (0x0D 0x0A). How can I configure it to terminate source code lines with Unix type line terminations? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, here's the answer. Rhapsody has a configuration setting, `UnixLineTerminationStyle`. If the checkbox for this is set, the code generator will produce code with Unix Line Termination Style.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, you can also tell Rhapsody you want to use an external editor.  That way you can use the editor of your choice.